# r: Create waterfall chart with ggvis instead of ggplot

Tags: r, charts, ggvis

I created the following waterfall chart with ggplot, based on this nice post http://analyticstraining.com/2015/waterfall-charts-using-ggplot2-in-r/

[image]

Now I want to create this chart in ggvis. I understand that there is a waterfall package which creates this kind of plot, but I want it in ggvis.
(Here is a link to the package https://www.r-bloggers.com/waterfall-plots-in-r/)

I started several attempts to create to the chart with ggvis, but by now I failed. The best I could do is the following with `layer_paths`:

[image]

I've tried to use `layer_bars`, which seems not work with negative values. I tried to use `layer_rects`, like in the ggplot, but I was not able to set the props for `ymin` and so on.

My knowledge about the inner workings of ggvis and Vega Marks is not very deep, can somebody give me a tip how I can succeed?

Here is the code for the two plots with example data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggvis)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)


test_data <- structure(list(id = 1:11,
                            process = c("Inventory", "Add_to_Storage", 
                                       "Remove_from_storage", "Remove_from_storage", "Remove_from_storage", "Remove_from_storage", 
                                       "Remove_from_storage", "Remove_from_storage", "Remove_from_storage", "Remove_from_storage", 
                                       "Remove_from_storage"), 
                            date = structure(c(16161,16161, 16161, 16161, 16161, 16161, 16161, 16161, 16161, 16161,16161), class = "Date"), 
                            timestamp = structure(1:11, .Label = c("00:00:01","10:04:00", "12:23:33", "12:43:23", "13:36:37", "19:08:27", "19:26:56", "19:49:41", "20:01:04", "20:02:27", "20:11:32"), class = "factor"), 
                            inv_yest = c(0,NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                            inv_added = c(NA, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                            inv_remove = c(NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
                            inv_change = c(0, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), 
                            inv_end = c(0,3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6), 
                            inv_start = c(0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5)
                            ), 
                       .Names = c("id", "process","date", "timestamp", "inv_yest", "inv_added", "inv_remove","inv_change","inv_end", "inv_start"), 
                       row.names = c(NA, -11L), 
                       class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
                       )

# Waterfall Plot with ggplot
ggplot(test_data,
       aes(x = timestamp,
           fill = process
           )
) +
  geom_rect(aes(x = timestamp,
                xmin = id - 0.45,
                xmax = id + 0.45,
                ymin = inv_end,
                ymax = inv_start
                )
  ) +
  geom_text(
    aes(
      x = timestamp,
      y = inv_end + 2,
      label = inv_change
    ),
    position = position_dodge(width = 1)
  ) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(
          lineheight=1.0,
          face="bold",
          hjust = 0.5
        ) 
  ) +
  ggtitle(paste0("Inventory development on day ",unique(test_data$date)))  # fügt Titel hinzu

# Add lower boundaries and only positive changes
test_data %>%
  dplyr::mutate(inv_lower = pmin(inv_start,inv_end)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(inv_upper = ifelse(inv_change < 0,inv_change*(-1),inv_change)) -> test_data


# Test with ggplot geom_step
ggplot() +
  geom_step(data=test_data, mapping=aes(x=timestamp, y=inv_end,group = 1)) +
  geom_step(data=test_data, mapping=aes(x=timestamp, y=inv_end,group = 1), 
            direction="vh", linetype=1) +
  geom_point(data=test_data, mapping=aes(x=timestamp, y=inv_end), color="red") 

# Test with ggvis layer_paths
# geom_step = layer_paths + transform_step # http://ggvis.rstudio.com/layers.html
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31395410/plotting-a-step-function-in-ggvis
test_data %>%
  ggvis(x=~timestamp,
        y=~inv_end
        ) %>%
  layer_paths(interpolate:="step-after"
              ) %>%
  layer_paths(interpolate:="step-before"
              ) %>%
  layer_points(fill:="red")
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ggvis and `layer_rects`, the arguments are `y` and `y2` instead of `ymin` and `ymax`.  I put `y2` and `fill` in the rectangle layer rather than in `ggvis`.

The width of the rectangles is set using `width` instead of manually via your "id" variable.

Setting the text position to the center takes a bit of work, and uses `"xcenter"` for "timestamp" and the `padding` argument in `scale_nominal`.

```
test_data %>%
    ggvis(x = ~timestamp, y = ~inv_end) %>%
    layer_rects(y2 = ~inv_start, width = band(),
              fill = ~process) %>%
    layer_text(x = prop("x", ~timestamp, scale = "xcenter"),
             y = ~inv_end + 2,
             text := ~inv_change) %>%
    scale_nominal("x", name = "xcenter", padding = .9)
```

[image]